# Excell autofill sheet 2 with sheet 1 info

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

Hi I hope you can help me. This is what I want to do.

### Sheet 1

```
s/n     product    price    brand
---     -------    -----    -----
1        chair     12       ikea
2        table     15       ikea
3       desktop    17       samsung
```

From 1 to 1000 on each cell I have information .

### Sheet 2

```
s/n   product   price   brand
```

### What I want

In black, so when I put a value (from sheet 1) in `s/n`, `product`, `price` and `brand` will auto-fill with the info from `Sheet 1` into `Sheet 2`.

Both sheets all starts on A1. I hope you can help.

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow! Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sheet 2 Cell B2 `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$1000,2,FALSE)` Copy down column

In Sheet 2 Cell C2 `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$1000,3,FALSE)` Copy down column

In Sheet 2 Cell D2 `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$1000,4,FALSE)` Copy down column

Comment: Thank you very much, all work has intented :) you are the man

Answer (score 0):

In Column B on Sheet 2, use a VLookup:

```
 =VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$D,2)
```

You can then copy this to Columns C & D, changing the last value to 3 & 4, respectively.

```
 =VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$D,3)
 =VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$D,4)
```

This can be copied to all rows on your spreadsheet, leaving column A blank. Then once you type in it will lookup the value

You can pretty it up by using a conditional for a value, so it appears blank if you have not entered anything:

```
 =IF($A2="","",VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$D,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Google Sheets because I don't have Excel; however, you can do the exact same thing.

**All you have to do is...**

**In Sheet 2:**

- `A1` : `=Sheet1!A1`
- `B1` : `=Sheet1!B1`
- `C1` : `=Sheet1!C1`
- Now, select all 3 cells
- click and drag the bottom-right corner of the selected cells
- Drag to row 1000

**Now, when ever you enter in data in Sheet 1, it will automatically fill out the same data in Sheet 2. No VLOOKUP needed!**

The image is in **Sheet 2**.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't let the user input their own s/n values and get the corresponding product, price and brand, which is something the OP described in the goal. I'm sure OP already knows how to make one cell mirror another.

Comment: I don't see that goal described in the question.

Comment: "when I put a value (from sheet 1) in s/n, product, price and brand will auto-fill"